# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error when I try to run this function. If you want to test it you can visit this site here: http://www.apdty.com/pluton

Click "Videos" at the top and mouse over one of the thumbnails. Then click the Plus sign. Error should show up in your browsers dev console. The code is supposed to stop the video when its playing. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ow3s692n/

```
function toggleVideo() {
                    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length;
                    var div = document.getElementById("popupVid");
                    for (var i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
                        var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[i].contentWindow;
                        iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}','*');
                        document.getElementById("mytext").value = i;
                    }
                }
```

Update: @Pointy was correct using document instead of div. I also made the error of pointing from an http location to an https location. You also have to remove "?rel=0" from your youtube links

Comment: You get the number of frames in the whole document, but then you iterate only through the frames inside that `<div>`. There are clearly fewer of those. Did you mean to use `document.getElementsByTagName()` inside the loop?

Comment: @Pointy Ah, you are correct. changing it from div to document fixes the error, but now it doesn't actually stop the videos...

Comment: Here is the updated http://jsfiddle.net/3cxt07e0/ which works. I also uploaded the new site file. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Its all fixed now. Updated OP. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Pointy